# Inserting session data to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
session_start(); 
if (!isset($_SESSION)){
}
$total_amt=$_POST['total_amt'];
   $total_seats=$_POST['total_seats'];
   $boarding_point=$_POST['boarding_point'];
   $_SESSION['total_amt']=$total_amt;
   $_SESSION['total_seats']=$total_seats;
   $_SESSION['boarding_point']=$boarding_point;
?>
<?php
require_once("config.php");
$source_point=$_SESSION['source_point'];
$destination=$_SESSION['destination'];
$datepick=$_SESSION['datepick'];
$_SESSION['total_amt']=$total_amt;
$_SESSION['total_seats']=$total_seats;
$boarding_point=$_POST['boarding_point'];

// Insert data into mysql
$sql="INSERT INTO book_seat(from, to, datepick, total_amt, total_seats,    boarding_point) VALUES 
    '{$_SESSION['source_point']}',
    '{$_SESSION['destination']}',
            '{$_SESSION['datepick']}',
    '{$_SESSION['total_amt']}',
            '{$_SESSION['total_seats']}',
        '{$_SESSION['boarding_point']}')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if(isset($_POST['chksbmt']) && !$errors) 
{
    header("location:booking_detail.php");
}
if(!$sql) die(mysql_error());

mysql_close();

?>
```

I want to insert my session variables to my database..

This is my code, there is no error happening, page is redirecting to booking_detail.php  but also these session variables are not getting inserted to my database also..

Comment: there is no error as i ve mentioned, bt my data are not getting inserted .

Comment: comment the line and retry and then check the error.. `//header("location:booking_detail.php");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`From` and `to` are reserved word,use backticks

[**Reserved words in Mysql**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html)

```
$sql="INSERT INTO book_seat(`from`, `to`, datepick, total_amt, total_seats,    boarding_point) VALUES 
    '{$_SESSION['source_point']}',
    '{$_SESSION['destination']}',
            '{$_SESSION['datepick']}',
    '{$_SESSION['total_amt']}',
            '{$_SESSION['total_seats']}',
        '{$_SESSION['boarding_point']}')";
```

Comment: its fixed .. i just changed my column name 'from' to leaving_from /. Now all the data are inserted xcept that leaving_from data , so i think i can fix that .. thank u 4 ur help ..

Comment: yeah only that 'from' and 'to' words are the problems

Answer (score 0):

Comment out your `header()`, turn on error reporting using `error_reporting(-1)`, check `mysql_error()` and then fix that problem.

From now I can see that you've got syntax error in sql query because you're using `from` as column name which is restricted word. You have to put it in `.

Answer (score 0):

1) Start session if its separate script.
2) Remove reserved keyword as suggested by @Mihai in your query.
3) In your query It should be `VALUES(` instead of `VALUES`.
4) As you are mention in your comment   `leaving_from` not inserting into Db.
   Because in your script you have not assign session value for `$_SESSION['source_point']` .

In your script will be :-

```
<?php
session_start(); 
   if (!isset($_SESSION)){
}

$total_amt  =   $_POST['total_amt'];
$total_seats =  $_POST['total_seats'];
$boarding_point =   $_POST['boarding_point'];

$_SESSION['total_amt']  =   $total_amt;
$_SESSION['total_seats']    =   $total_seats;
$_SESSION['boarding_point'] =   $boarding_point;
// Set here session value for $_SESSION['source_point'] as well,
```

Comment: Can you echo your DB query and run into query browser.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from, to, datepick, total_amt, total_seats, boarding_point) VALUES ' at line 1


the error

Comment: its fixed .. i just change my column name from to leaving_from /. Now all the data are inserted xcept that , so i think i can fix that .. thank u 4 ur help

Comment: Welcome @Pooja ji..:)

Comment: bt my leaving_from data is not getting inserted

Answer (score 0):

First remove quotes from all session variables like:

```
{$_SESSION['source_point']}
```

Second you're redirecting before `mysql_error` check, Check on results and error first and then redirect:

```
if (!$result) {
  die(mysql_error());
}

if(isset($_POST['chksbmt']) && !$errors) 
{
 header("location:booking_detail.php");
}
```

Comment: but v need to give quotes when we declare something in VALUES na

Comment: ohh i did that n got my error :

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from, to, datepick, total_amt, total_seats, boarding_point) VALUES ' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

remove the space from top

```
<?php session_start();
```

---

if this didn't work

`var_dump($_SESSION)` before inserting to check value exist in the session
 and use `die(mysql_error());` with the query

```
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());;
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from, to, datepick, total_amt, total_seats, boarding_point) VALUES ' at line 1 :
i got this erro

Comment: its fixed .. i just change my column name from to leaving_from /. Now all the data are inserted xcept that , so i think i can fix that .. thank u 4 ur help

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['chksbmt']) && !$errors) 
{
header("location:booking_detail.php");

}
```

Above code will be executed once the form is submitted if `chksbmt` is the name of the submit button.
It takes to that page mentioned in header before inserting.
Write all your stuff in between above curly braces, use

```
if(isset($_POST['chksbmt']) && !$errors) 
{
 //all your stuff, ex:storing in DB.
  if($result){
   header("location:booking_detail.php");

  }
}
```

I hope that I've understood your problem, this will workout.

Comment: its fixed .. i just changed my column name 'from' to 'leaving_from' /. Now all the data are inserted xcept that , so i think i can fix that .. thank u 4 ur help